# Jenkins Pipeline Configuration page cannot reach GIT unless Windows service user has Devops account

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am using Jenkins Pipeline to execute one complex spatial data migration. Jenkins is running as a service on a windows server. All our scripts including main Groovy script are located in GIT. Problem which I have is that Pipeline Configuration page has a problem reaching GIT repository unless user which starts Jenkins service has a account in Azure Devops.

If the Jenkins service is started with a user who doesn’t have account in Devops, following error message is visible on the Job configuration page:

Failed to connect to repository : Command "git.exe ls-remote -h -- https://xxxxxxx.visualstudio.com/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/_git/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx HEAD" returned status code 128:
stdout:
stderr: Logon failed, use ctrl+c to cancel basic credential prompt.
fatal: Authentication failed for ' https://xxxxxxx.visualstudio.com/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/_git/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx '

[Screen of the error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uc2wB.png)

Account which is mentioned in the Credentials dropdown is somehow ignored. I actually expect that Jenkins tries reaching GIT immediately using this account.

If I start the Windows service with the same account as given above in the Credentials dropdown, Jenkins does not show error message here and Jobs can be started properly.

Does someone have maybe some solution other than starting Jenkins Windows service with Devops account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the GitSCM plugin completely ignores the provided credentials. Possible reason is that Jenkins can't use integrated security to authenticate against Azure DevOps. One of the explanation found is that we will not be able to authenticate with Microsoft ID as Jenkins is not able to get the encrypted token.

Most simple way to get over this problem was for me to create a Personal Access Token that will be used by the Jenkins Pipeline process to access the code repository.
Personal Access Token can be created on the Tokens page.

Generated token will be used as a password for a special credential which will have access to the GIT repository of Azure DevOps. 
This user will be saved in Jenkins Credentials:

- Username: “token”
- Password: token value received on Personal Access Tokens page

Answer (score 0):

Use ssh url to clone or switch tfs auth to basic. Jenkins can't use integrated security to authenticate